# Aws public ip in runing instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When i do ***ifconfig*** in my EC2 instance I get private IP. But adding to *sites-available* in my apache I need public ip.

Is there any way i can get my public IP in my running instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "magic IP" on amazon EC2 instaces which you can curl for metadata about your instance.

To get the public IP of a current instance you can do:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

You can read the full documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html).

Comment: Yup figured it out. Thank you for help.